# Constructing a SqlAlchemy exists query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `prizes` and `prize_unlocks`. I'm trying to write a query to find a prize that a user has not previously unlocked.

The idea is that there is a table of prizes that can be won by any user and there is a table tracking which users have won which prizes. I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and the tables are defined like this:

```
class Prize(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'prizes'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  # ... some other info about the prize...


class PrizeUnlock(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'prize_unlocks'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

  # associated prize
  prize_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('prizes.id'))
  prize = db.relationship('Prize',
    backref=db.backref('prize_unlocks'))

  # associated user
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
  user = db.relationship('User',
    backref=db.backref('prize_unlocks'))
```

I am trying to write a single SqlAlchemy query to select a random prize from the prizes that a user has *not* previously won. As I understand, I need to write the query with an `exists` clause, but I'm unable to get it right.

Could anyone please help out with this?

If it's of any help, the corresponding sql query looks like this:

`select p.id from prizes as p where not exists (select * from prize_unlocks where prize_unlocks.prize_id=r.id) order by rand() limit 1;`

EDIT: Got the answer! metmirr was very close, but I'm just posting the final answer here in case it helps someone in the future.

```
db.session.query(Prize.id).filter(
  not_(
    db.session.query(PrizeUnlock)
      .filter(Prize.id == PrizeUnlock.prize_id)
      .exists()
  )
).order_by(Prize.id).limit(10).all()
```

Comment: What's the wrong query that you wrote? Perhaps we could help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use subquery in filter function:

```
db.session.query(Prize.id).filter(
    db.session.query(PrizeUnlock.id)
        .filter(Prize.id == PrizeUnlock)
        .exists()
).order_by(Prize.id).limit(1)
```

Comment: Sweet, this was close enough to the answer that I found it. Thanks!